Security of encoding json files on a wep App
I didn't see this discussed so I'm asking. I have a WinForm program and I would try to replicate it as a web App but one of the main things that concern me is "when something is online, it's totally exposed". So, one thing I do with my program is encoding the resource text json files content to make it less readable for an average user (provided that the average user has no means to do that while I find it hard to believe an experienced one would have any interest in cracking it or something). Since creating a web App would expose much more the content on the web, I thought I could use any stronger method for encoding the files or something. One idea I got is first encoding the content and then add some random text at the beginning and the end of the content so, in theory, only I would know what part of that file is the one I need to be decoded to be read by the App. Would this be a good idea? Also, I don't even still know if encoding is a possibility using JS, but I suppose it is...?
